# Conversion of words into definitions

Tags: modifiers

‘Very sharp’

> Sharp: having an edge or point that is able to cut or pierce something.
>
> Very: in a high degree.

What word of the definition of ‘sharp’ is modified by ‘in a high degree’? I think it’s weird ‘having’ is modified by ‘in a high degree,’ but is a head of a phrase modified by a head of a phrase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"head modifies head" Not necessarily. I don't think there's any simple rule for how you would put two definitions together.

Definitions are tricky. It's often very difficult to describe the meaning of a word with just a few other words. If you tried to replace every word in a sentence with its definition from a dictionary, the result would likely be a confusing mess. You have to read the definition and try to understand the sense of it.

In this case, yes, "sharp" means "having an edge or point that is able to cut or pierce". Usually this is understood to mean that the point or edge tapers until it ends up extremely narrow. So "very sharp" means "coming to a very narrow point or edge" or "very much able to cut or pierce".